# SQL query -- need to be sure I have this logic right

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have code below and I would appreciate some help making sure this is correct. (slow day)

```
Select 
    A.Label, A.Name, C.UID, D.Unit 
From 
    A 
inner join 
    B on A.UID = B.FUID 
left join 
   C on B.UID = C.UID
left join 
   D on C.unitID = D.ID
Where 
   C.LName = 'Gas'
```

The code above reads -- get all Labels, and corresponding Name, in `Table A` that are linked to a record in `Table B` which may or may not have a record linked to it in C, and which may or may not have record linked to it in D, and `C.LName = 'gas'`.

Is this correct please? What I need is to pull data from A that exist in B regardless of whether record exists in C or D.

Comment: You should have `.. INNER JOIN B ON A.UID = B.FUID` - use the `ON` keyword - not `WHERE` - in join conditions.

Comment: Where does `F.UID` come from in your query? Do you have a table `F`?

Answer (score 0):

No.

You need to put the filter for 'Gas' in the join, otherwise the left join will effectively be an inner join

```
Select  
    A.Label, A.Name, C.UID, D.Unit  
From  
    A  
inner join B on A.UID = B.FUID  
left join C on B.UID = C.UID 
            and C.LName = 'Gas'
left join D on C.unitID = D.ID
```

Comment: Will that make a difference in this case?

Comment: @Kobojunkie That depends on your data - what is the reasoning behind your left join from b to c?

Comment: I need to return a row for each record in A that joins successfully  to B, and also bring back, if any, values in C and D for the row.

Comment: @Kobojunkie In that case, yes. Your query would only bring back rows where there was a value in C - not where there wasn't.

Comment: How do I change it to bring back rows when there is a value or none in C?

Comment: @Kobojunkie use the above sql

Answer (score 0):

Use `ON A.UID = B.FUID` instead of `where A.UID = B.FUID` like so:

```
Select A.Label, A.Name , FUID, D.Unit 
From A 
inner join B ON A.UID = B.FUID 
left join C ON B.UID = C.UID
left join D on C.unitID = D.ID
Where C.LName = 'Gas'
```